Is it possible to aggregate data at custom Looker Studio connector side?
I am developing custom Looker Studio connector that sends request to backend and retrieve data from the MySQL database. Instead of passing all the raw data to the Looker Studio
I would like to process the data on my own backend in the similar way how it works with the original MySQL connector.
The quesion is how to get the required metrics on the Looker Studio connector side to pass them to backend to prepare data according specific request?
I tried to find something about this in the official documentation,
tried digging into request data but did not find anything.
